# How to return value from json-server on post request?

Tags: json-server

The issue

- `GET /api/get-request` works correctly, and `{ x: 'x' } is returned to the frontend
- `POST /api/post-request` works too but returns **empty body**

How I run json-server:

> json-server src/configs/api/mocks/json-server-generator.js --routes src/configs/api/mocks/json-server-routes.json --watch"

**json-server-routes.json**

```
{
  "/api/getrequest": "/getrequest",
  "/api/postrequest": "/postrequest",
 
}
```

**json-server-generator.js**

```
module.exports = () => {
   return {
      getrequest: { x: 'x' },
      postrequest: { y: 'y' }
   }
}
```

Requests are made via `fetch`:

```
fetch(url, { 
   method,
   headers: {
      'content-type': 'application/json'
    },
   body: JSON.stringify(payload)
})
```